# How to config MathJax for reveal.js when running offline?

Tags: mathjax, reveal.js, offline-mode

In the reveal.js documentation, the [MathJax section](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#mathjax) says that normally, MathJax is loaded from a remote server, and if you want to use MathJax offline you'll need to download a copy of the library and adjust the `mathjax` configuration value.

The configuration I'm trying is

```
math: {
    mathjax: 'MathJax/MathJax.js',
    config: 'TeX-AMS_HTML-full'
}
```

where `MathJax/MathJax.js` is the relative address of the `MathJax.js` file in a clone of the MathJax repository I have locally on my computer.

When I first load a page in the presentation with equations on it (or reload it by pressing F5 in the browser), I first see the LaTeX code for the equations for a short while, before seeing a rendering that looks very basic and not very nice but still okay, but then finally I see what looks like a nice rendering of the equations, but with thick frames around every character in the equations which completely mess up everything.

**How should MathJax be configured properly, so that it looks identical to when MathJax is loaded from a remote server?**

Comment: Random guess is that the effect is due to some aggressive CSS in the page. does this happen when loading from the CDN?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger What do you mean by loading from the CDN? What's CDN?

Comment: With "CDN" I meant loading a copy from a service like cdnjs (or our old cdn.mathjax.org copy which is no longer available). Without a link to a live sample, it's hard to help. Another random guess is that your server is not able to serve webfonts correctly (see [the docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html#notes-about-shared-installations)) and thus it has to fallback to the ancient "PNG fonts" (which are images and might get borders from reveal.js's CSS).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger What do you mean by "my server"? I'm not running a local server as far as I know. Should I? I don't see that the reveal.js documentation says that MathJax needs a server in order to work. In that case I will use node.js as suggested on the page, but how do I set it up to work together with MathJax?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a server. But there's not enough information to help.